# Office Web Add-ins - Internal error when saving settings

Tags: office-js, office-addins, word-web-addins

I'm getting an failure when trying to save my document settings. The message is the following: `{"name":"Internal Error","message":"An internal error has occurred.","code":5001}`

My code:

```
Office.context.document.settings.set('token', token);
Office.context.document.settings.set('email', email);
Office.context.document.settings.saveAsync(function (asyncResult) {
   if (asyncResult.error) {
      displayError(asyncResult.error.message);
   }
});
```

The problem revealed when I  reinstalled my OS (Windows 10) and does not exist in Office for Mac and Web. It happens both on PowerPoint and Word. 
Maybe it's something with file write permissions?

[EDIT]
I suspect it may be the problem with the last office.js release. I'm using the official CDN (https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/office.js) or with the last Office 365 update for Windows Clients (16.0.11727.20222). The problem exists in Outlook as well when trying to save `roamingSettings`. The message then is: `{"name":"GenericSettingsError","message":"Permission denied","code":9019}`

Comment: I'm seeing a similar issue with Excel: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57137876/settings-api-for-office-add-ins-office-js-is-not-working-in-excel

Comment: Hi @MichaelSaunders, there is an issue with the lastest Office for Windows version. Please follow this issue on github: https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/626

Comment: This is a recent regression which we have indentified. We are currently working to rollout the fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue has been fix with Outlook Version 1907 (build 11901.20176). It is enough to update the Office to get rid of it.

[GitHub page with an issue](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/626#issuecomment-516184111)