# Web Addins on updated outlook client not working, F12 Debugger 'SCRIPT70: Permission denied'

Tags: angular5, office-js, office-addins, outlook-web-addins, outlook-2016

We have developed outlook Addins and hosted on Apache Server with SSL certicate installed with it. Some days back it was working absolutely fine on both web as well office outlook client, after windows update and client update it returns Empty blank screen?

Till the Outlook Client version 1808 all looks good in client. After the Update to outlook client 1902 Addin Stopped working on outlook client.

[image: version]

The error message in F12 Debugger is thrown is :

[image: error denied]

Everything was working fine before update,

Note that this addin is build on **Angular version 5** frame work using routes.

Update: I was loading office.js locally from the project not from the CDN, Now when I changes the office.js path in index.html to the cdn link "https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/office.js" Addins started working back.

But I need something not from CDN because one of our customer has on-primises server and not the office365 .So the problem I found is the office.js loading the outlook-win32.02.js but saying permision denied if loaded from the project and not from the CDN link.

Hope to get some suggestions from the outlook web addin Team....

Comment: This is probably the same issue I have: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57055215/office-web-add-ins-internal-error-when-saving-settings. There is a failure when saving settings

Comment: Not exactly, I am facing this problem only in outlook client and it works fine in OWA also , only after updating from  1808 to 1902 all problems started, I think in my case some thing wrong with iframe in which my agular app is running inside the Office Outlook Client.

Comment: Does it work in outlook.com?

Comment: Yes it works on web .

Comment: Set callback in your `saveAsync()` function and debug the `result`. If it's `failed`, check out the error code.

Comment: Ajit, I think you're getting the same thing that we are getting.  The NuGet package is older than the CDN version, and I suspect Microsoft fixed some issues in the CDN version that is not in the NuGet package.  I posted this today: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57149430/nuget-office-js-is-different-older-than-cdn-office-js

Comment: @BrianClink please follow the my answer if it solves your problem too

Comment: Thanks again, we decided to use this distribution which also fixes our issue: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@microsoft/office-js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After lots of reasearch I decided to use CDN link "https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/Office.js", and every thing started work as like before,

Then I decided compare my office.js inside the library with the CDN link javascript then I came to know that office script library is updated and I m having an old package, after reseach I found the github project updated recently , the below link will directly takes to the updated libraby , one can download with your existing one,

"https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/tree/release/dist" .

Hope this works for all having this issue.

Comment: Here is another distribution that may also work: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@microsoft/office-js

Comment: Yes you are that can be also a solution.