# NuGet Office js is different (older) than CDN Office js

Tags: outlook-web-addins

The NuGet and the CDN versions are different. They have the same file version: /* Version: 16.0.6807.1000 */, but the CDN includes /* Update: 2 */ in the header, and there are some changes in the code itself.

Using the NuGet version, we receive "Permission Denied" when loading outlook-win32-16.01.js file in Outlook desktop. The file calls invokeHostMethod which itself calls window.external.Execute and that's when the exception is thrown. Office JS stops loading and the add-in does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, to some degree by design. NuGet gets updated only on major releases, last one ~3 weeks ago. As suggested by Brian the right way to get the latest and greatest is to use NPM https://www.npmjs.com/package/@microsoft/office-js

Answer (score 0):

I found the github project updated recently for office js, the below link will directly takes to the updated libraby , one can download with your existing one,

"https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/tree/release/dist" .

Comment: Thanks, Ajit, we are looking into your suggestion!

Comment: Thanks again, we decided to use this distribution which also fixes our issue: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@microsoft/office-js