# RoamingSettings.saveAsync returning permission denied error on desktop only

Tags: angular, office-js, outlook-web-addins

I have an Outlook Add-in that has been out for a couple of months now in the office store.

Currently we save some important details to the roaming settings to save the user typing in the same information again.

As it stands we save a boolean value, a string which contains a URL and a string which contains a Guid which is an access token to be used by the user when querying our external API through the add-in.

All calls to store into the roaming settings are done via the following method:

```
  public setItemIntoRoamingSettings<T>(name: string, item: T) {
  Office.context.roamingSettings.set(name, item);
  Office.context.roamingSettings.saveAsync(function(asyncResult) {
    console.log(asyncResult);
  });
```

Lately we've had some clients report that the desktop version of the Add-In is no longer working.

After some investigation I've found that the reason why is the Access token is no longer being saved.  Strangely the URL and boolean value is saving fine.  And when the user uses the Webmail version of Outlook everything saves fine; this issue is only occurring in the desktop version of Outlook.

I've checked the logging we're getting back when the call fails and what we're getting is the following error:

```
{ 
 error:
  { 
    code: 9019,
    message: "Permission Denied",
    name:  "GenericSettingsError"
   },
 status: "failed"
}
```

The current permission level for the Add-In in the manifest is ReadWriteItem.  For the sake of testing I tried changing the permissions to ReadWriteMailbox to see if that would resolve the issue but it did not.

Is anyone aware of why this permission denied error has started occurring and how I can get around it?

Comment: I have the same problem, also with the add-in already published in the Store:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57055215/office-web-add-ins-internal-error-when-saving-settings

Comment: I've also created an issue on GitHub. https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/626 Maybe you can comment there to let them know it's not a separated problem

Comment: Have added to your github post to help raise visibility on it.

Comment: This is a recent regression which we have indentified. We are currently working to rollout the fix.

Comment: @ Outlook Add-ins Team - MSFT is this Fixed ?