# Settings API for office add-ins (Office.js) is not working in Excel

Tags: office-js, office-addins

In my Excel add-in, I save settings via the common Settings API, like this:

```js
Office.context.document.settings.set("user-selected-stock","MSFT");
Office.context.document.settings.saveAsync();
```

Starting about a week ago, many of my add-in users have begun complaining that this feature is no longer working. I was able to confirm that the problem is an issue with Excel, because a user was able to reproduce the issue with the People Graph add-in, which is built by Microsoft and preinstalled by default. Here are the **repro steps**:

1. New workbooks > Insert > People Graph (the green button beside Add-ins)
2. When it loads, click inside and click the gear (settings) icon in the top right. You should see some settings slide in from the right hand side.
3. Switch from the white background to the yellow background in the settings pane.
4. Save the workbook and close it.
5. Reopen the workbook.

**Expected**: see the yellow background (persisted by the Settings API)

**Actual**: see the white background (Settings not persisted). When I examine the WebExtension XML part in the file, the "properties" node, where Settings should be stored, appears empty.

**Environment:**
Office Home & Student 2016
Excel Version 1906, Build 11727.20244
Windows 10

Is this a known issue?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is a known issue. Team is working hard to fix it and it is in the processing of releasing. Thanks a lot for reporting it.

Comment: A reference to said issue would be helpful: https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/626