# How to disable outlook add-in for Outlook 2013 desktop version

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-web-addins, office365-apps

i have a outlook add-in and i want to hide/disable add-in for outlook 2013 users .
how can i achieve it using manifest file ? 
Here is my host element in manifest file

```
<Hosts>
    <Host Name="Mailbox" />
</Hosts>
<Requirements>
    <Sets>
      <Set Name="Mailbox" MinVersion="1.1" />
    </Sets>
</Requirements>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set your `MinVersion` to a requirement set that is not supported by Outlook 2013/2016 one-time purchase (1.5 is the earliest) which will prevent your add-in from being shown in clients that don't support that requirement set.

However, depending on what version of Exchange you are using, you may be limited by what requirement set Exchange supports. See [this table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/requirement-sets/outlook-api-requirement-sets#clients) for what requirement sets each Outlook or Exchange version supports.

Update in response to DavidT's notes. David is indeed correct that Outlook 2013/Outlook 2016 (One time Purchase) clients, support the same API Requirement Sets. However, later versions of Outlook (Office 365 or Outlook 2019 One Time Purchase), support higher API Sets. So using this method will drop out Outlook 2016/2013.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that there is currently no way to disable an addin for Outlook 2013 and keep it enabled for Outlook 2016.
[Outlook Add-ins Team have misread the question. The issue is how to disable an add-in for Outlook 2013 and keep it enabled for Outlook 2016.]
Currently that is not possible because the requirements sets are identical for Outlook 2013 and Outlook 2016, so there is no way to differentiate using requirement sets. This is a problem because there is an issue with Outlook 2013 that is fixed in Outlook 2016. Any add-in using the element broken in 2013 will not be able to pass the tests to get added to the Office store because it won't work in Outlook 2013 and there is no way to say don't use for Outlook 2013.
[Office Web Add-ins - Internal error when saving settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57055215/office-web-add-ins-internal-error-when-saving-settings)

Comment: Updated our response below.