# Outlook Add-in - How to declare that our add-in does not support versions of outlook that uses IE11

Tags: outlook, internet-explorer-11, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I am trying to get our app certified in the MS office store, for outlook.
Right now our add-in is not working on Microsoft 365 versions earlier than 16.0.11629 on Windows 10. This is because we don't support IE11 and the versions earlier than 16.0.11629 are using IE11 internally in Windows.

Any elegant way around this?

I see in the following thread a way to just declare that we don't support
[How to disable outlook add-in for Outlook 2013 desktop version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58098019/how-to-disable-outlook-add-in-for-outlook-2013-desktop-version)

But is this an acceptable solution for certification from Microsoft?

Comment: Setting the Min RequrimentSet to 1.5 will put you out of range of Outlook 2013/2016 (which only support IE) So that is a good first step. However, there isn't really a way to detect that a user hasn't upgraded Office / Windows to a version that supports Edge / WebView2. 

You could add something into your add-in that detects browser type, and display an error message asking the user to upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this issue, Change the RequirementSet to 1.5 and also add a fallback UI.

```
  var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;
  var trident = ua.indexOf("Trident/");
  var msie = ua.indexOf("MSIE ");
  if (trident > 0 || msie > 0) { /* enable fallback ui */ }
```